# How can I install JDK on 32 bit Windows 10?

Tags: java, android

How can I install the Java Development Kit on 32 bit Windows 10? It says This app can't run on your computer. I don't have 64 bit windows. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't try to install the x64 version of the JDK, but the x86 version.

Comment: as your question is tagged Android : recent version of Android Studio include a JDK  (OpenJDK), so just install a 32-bit Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you download JDK from below website. Windowsx86 is a 32 bit JDK. After install it

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html